# The [asyncio] tag overlaps with the [python-asyncio] tag and should be merged

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

In my opinion, [asyncio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asyncio) and [python-asyncio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-asyncio) overlap each other, so these should be merged together.

Because in raising a question we could add only five tags, and it prevents choosing other relevant tags. Also, it could make bad tracking `asyncio` issues on Stack Overflow.

---

[**NOTE**]:

- Those tags detail is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before a merge like this, it is important to verify that the [asyncio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asyncio) tag is only being used for questions related to [python-asyncio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-asyncio). If it is, those questions should be manually retagged *before* completing the merge, when it is easier to find them.

To this end, I used [a search query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Basyncio%5D+is%3Aquestion+-%5Bpython*%5D&mixed=0) that found all questions that were tagged [asyncio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asyncio) but lacked any tags related to Python. There were 11 such questions. I either manually retagged these questions, confirmed that they did actually have to do with Python's asyncio library even though they were not tagged with any Python tags (e.g., they were tagged with [flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flask), [plotly-dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plotly-dash), [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas)), or closed/deleted questions that needed to be removed anyway.

The only one I was unsure about was this one: [trying to setup connexion.AioHttpApp() with aiohttp-cors for async routes fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57425403/trying-to-setup-connexion-aiohttpapp-with-aiohttp-cors-for-async-routes-fails). Please feel free to jump in there and retag, if appropriate, based on your knowledge of the subject matter. I am not a Python programmer.

Afterwards, I merged the [asyncio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asyncio) tag into the [python-asyncio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-asyncio) tag.

I did not create a synonym, considering the risk of tagging mistakes. It is too easy for folks to think that a [asyncio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asyncio) tag is appropriate for general questions about asynchronous I/O, not realizing it is limited to the Python library. The tag suggestion box will still show [python-asyncio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-asyncio) as an option whenever an asker types in "asyncio".

Comment: Thanks for the time effort. I checked the mentioned your unsure link post, and edit it: that was irrelevant to the `python-asyncio`, while [connecxion](https://github.com/zalando/connexion) is an asynchronous library.

Comment: Thanks for following up, @Benyamin.